# How to override GetHashCode on a Hashtable?

Tags: c#, hashtable, gethashcode

I would like override the `GetHashCode` method on a hashtable in C#.

I use the hashtable as a multidimensional key in a complex object.

How could do that ?

Different order of Keys in `hKey` must return the same `hashCode`.

Something like this doesn't work:

```
Hashtable hkey; 

int i = 0;
foreach (DictionaryEntry de in hkey)
    i ^= de.GetHashCode();

return i;
```

Comment: What have you tried? You could potentially override `GetHashCode` by inheriting the class you want to alter, and then use the new child class instead.

Comment: Why you still use a `HashTable` and not a `Dictionary<SomeType, SomeType>`?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32024/calculating-gethashcode-efficiently-with-unordered-list

Comment: Hmm, the XOR operator does not care about order so the "doesn't work" complaint is not helpful.  GetHashCode() becomes useless very quickly when it becomes too slow, iterating an entire collection is not correct.  Consider `return hkey.Count;`

Comment: See my post below the problem came from the GetHashCode of dictionaryEntry which only take account the Key part.
About performance, I keep cache of HashCode ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can override GetHashCode() of a Hashtable if you extend it as such:

```
public class MyHashtable : Hashtable
{
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        const int seed = 1009;
        const int factor = 9176;

        var hash = seed;
        foreach (var key in Keys)
        {
            hash = hash * factor + key.GetHashCode();
        }

        return hash;
    }
}
```

Constants were taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34006336/8006950

More on hashing: http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ok this work fine , thanks to all

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Hashtable h = new Hashtable()
        {
          { "string1", 1 },
          { "string2", 2 }
        };

        int i = GetHashCode(h);

        h = new Hashtable()
        {
          { "string2", 2},
          { "string1", 1 }
        };

        int j = GetHashCode(h);

        Debug.Assert(i == j);

        h = new Hashtable()
        {
          { "string1", 1 },
          { "string2", 2 }
        };

        i = GetHashCode(h);

        h = new Hashtable()
        {
          { "string2", 3},
          { "string1", 1 }
        };

        j = GetHashCode(h);

        Debug.Assert(i != j);
    }

    static int GetHashCode(Hashtable ht)
    {
        if (ht.Count == 0) return ht.GetHashCode();

        int h = 0;
        foreach(DictionaryEntry de in ht)
        {
            h ^= new { de.Key, de.Value }.GetHashCode();
        }
        return h;
    }
```